# My collections are not empty but return empty array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nginx, collections

im using **mongoDB** and registered many users in my website.So i know that user collection is not empty but i can not see my collections. can you help me with that?

[image]

i attach my other parts maybe it could help you to find the problem.

[image]

i think i should authorized user to see mongo.
thank you all.

Comment: Most probably you have switched to different  database ... , try "use [corrrect database name]" :)

Comment: `persianLocals` vs. `persionlocalguides`

Comment: you right. but i had uploaded wrong photo. I corrected that, anyway, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your register works properly I wouldn't worry, this is expected behavior. Your collection is just very very small so it's size is rounded down.

I recommend you run `db.stats()` to check data stats of db. The results would look like this:

```
{
    "db" : "local",
    "collections" : 1,
    "objects" : 15,
    "avgObjSize" : 123.4,
    "dataSize" : 660,
    "storageSize" : 60960,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 1,
    "indexSize" : 20960,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This way you can confirm if your db is actually empty. If it is then I'd check the register route logic.

Comment: THanks for your time. i tested this command and got this result:

{
        "db" : "persianlocalguides",
        "collections" : 0,
        "views" : 0,
        "objects" : 0,
        "avgObjSize" : 0,
        "dataSize" : 0,
        "storageSize" : 0,
        "totalSize" : 0,
        "indexes" : 0,
        "indexSize" : 0,
        "scaleFactor" : 1,
        "fileSize" : 0,
        "fsUsedSize" : 0,
        "fsTotalSize" : 0,
        "ok" : 1
} 
It semms that this is not my DB, so ... how can i see my db

Comment: `persianlocalguides` is not your DB? you did execute `use persianlocalguides` in your question.

Comment: yes, i execute `use persianlocalguides` and i can see list of my users in my website. so im sure that the collections hav been createdm, but i can not see collections in mongo db shell.

Comment: any chance you're connected to the wrong mongo db?

Comment: You were right. I was working with a wrong name database